# UI Framework for CrossPlatform Development

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform, user-experience

I am looking for a UI framework that can help in providing end-user experience on different platforms using a single code-base. The platforms I am targeting includes Windows, Android (phone, tablet, tv, watch), Chromebook, Linux, macOS, iOS, iPadOS, tvOS, watchOS etc.
Does anyone have any suggestions on what all frameworks are present out there that can be tried  ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [AlterNET UI](https://alternet-ui.com/), it's a cross-platform .NET UI framework, primarily targeting desktop applications development.

It's still in the early betas, we're about to release beta 2 with WPF-like features like support for layouts, bindings, dependency properties, routed events and handling keyboard/mouse input.

These are other frameworks we looked at before coming up with own solution: JavaFX, Electron, Qt, AvaloniaUI and MAUI, you may read a bit more information [here](https://www.alternet-ui.com/blog/introducing-alternet-ui).